# Proving $\mathbb{R}^3 \textrm{\\} {0}$ not Lie group, without using homotopy equivalence?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872686/finding-a-lie-group-structure-on-mathbb-rn-setminus-0), I found that Lie group structure cannot be granted onto $\mathbb{R}^n \textrm{\\} {0}$ for odd `n`. I am specifically interested in the minimal case, which is `n = 3`.

The answer there is based on a short comment, which involves homotopy equivalence and Euler characteristic. I am fairly unfamiliar with these concepts, so I wonder if there is an easier way to achieve this proof.
(In particular, I also dislike that it uses Euler characteristic, which seems to be involved concept for general manifolds)

There is also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844409/with-which-binary-action-is-the-2-sphere-a-lie-group?noredirect=1), but $\mathbb{R}^3 \textrm{\\} {0}$ part is  not proved.

Is there more specific, perhaps painstaking way to prove that $\mathbb{R}^3 \textrm{\\} {0}$ can never be a Lie group?

Comment: Also I am curious what happens if we cut out more "holes". Would it continue to be inadmissible to Lie group? Would R^n with holes stop being Lie group for even n as well?

Comment: First, $\Bbb R^3\setminus 0$ is homotopy equivalent to the sphere $S^2$, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761205/what-is-the-second-homotopy-group-of-r3-setminus-0-0-0). This is not so difficult, and it is useful anyway (even necessary) that you learn this definition. Then we have elementary proofs at MSE, why this isn't a Lie group, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1262320/why-is-s2-not-a-lie-group).

Comment: Definition of homotopy equivalence by itself does not seem difficult, but I cannot make the connection to Lie group (or the homeomorphism without fixpoint). Does auto-homeomorphsms on $\mathbb{R}^3$ \ $0$ translate to $S^2$?

Comment: I understand. My idea was, to "view" $\Bbb R^3\setminus 0$ simply as $S^2$. Then things are easier. You can also use the results of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3481290/can-every-manifold-be-turned-into-a-lie-group), but this is also not elementary.

Comment: Using $\pi_2(M) \neq 0$ would be way over my head. How do I "view" $\mathbb{R}^3$ \ $0$ as $S^2$? Hairy ball theorem does not extend to this manifold, so I cannot apply the same logic. Sorry, I banged my head at this and am utterly lost..

Comment: You cannot beat something with nothing. You are asking an advanced question and, yet, refuse to accept advanced tools for answering it. Afaik, using $\pi_2$ is the simplest way to solve this. Alternatives involve structural results for Lie groups, which are harder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really cannot avoid learning some algebraic topology to answer this question: using "bare hands" I don't even know how to show that $\mathbb{R}^3$ (which is obviously a Lie group) is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ (try it!), whereas with some algebraic topology they can be easily distinguished using $\pi_2$ or $H_2$ or the Euler characteristic.

The question of Lie group structures on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$ is also related to the classification of real [division algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)) (if an $n$-dimensional division algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ exists then its multiplication induces a Lie group structure on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$ and also on $S^{n-1}$; we know by the classification that this occurs only when $n = 2$ and $n = 4$, and $S^1$ and $S^3$ are the only positive-dimensional spheres with Lie group structures) which requires some unavoidable actual work to establish one way or another.

Comment: I see, then it seems that this was harder than I thought. I guess $S^2$ with its always vanishing vector field is the most trivial case then.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like homotopy topology ), then you can use Lie group theory. The space under consideration may be diffeomorphic only to some three-dimensional simply connected Lie group. Its maximal compact subgroup must be diffeomorphic to $S^2$. But the two-dimensional sphere is not a Lie group (there are only two two-dimensional simply connected Lie groups, and both of them are solvable and diffeomorphic to $R^2$).

In short, the absence of a Lie group structure in the indicated space follows easily from the description of the structure of three-dimensional simply connected Lie groups. (In this case, the Euler characteristic is not used!)

Comment: What is the argument that ensures that the maximally compact subgroup must be $S^2$? Why not a torus, a point, a circle?